# Relation between zero stability and absolute stability of numerical methods for solving ODEs

Tags: numerical-methods

I'm confused by the relationship between the notions of zero stability and absolute stability in numerical analysis. Consider the leapfrog method given by:

$y_{k+2} =y_k + 2hf(t_{k+1},y_{k+1}) $

It is known that this method has stability region $S=\{z \in \mathbb{C} | Re(z)=0, |Im(z)|<1\}$, where $z=\lambda h$. Therefore no step size $h>0$, however small, will cause the numerical process to remain bounded when applied to the test problem $y' = \lambda y$, meaning:

$max_{k\geq 0}|y_k - \tilde{y_k}|= \infty$ for any $h>0$

However, the characteristic polynomial associated with this method satisfies the root condition, and therefore it must be zero stable, meaning there exist strictly positive constants $h^*, K$ such that:

$max_{k\geq 0}|y_k - \tilde{y_k}|<K max_{k\geq 0}|w_k|$ for $0<h<h^*$

Where $w_k$ are input errors at step $k$.

Given these definitions, it seems impossible for a method to be zero stable but not to remain bounded for any $h>0$. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure it is supposed to be $y_{\color{red}{k+2}}$?

Comment: Yes I made an error thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @mattos : This is the central Euler method or 2-step Nystrom method, with the cited weak stability.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes, there was a factor of $2$ missing which made it confusing.

Comment: My sincere apologies!

Comment: Let me know on the last day of the bounty if no one has answered it yet.

Comment: @NikeDattani it's the last day

Comment: Can you first see if page 9 of [this review I wrote 13 years ago](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.4965) has any helpful hints? It's almost 2:30am here in Waterloo, Ontario and I can't write a full answer.

Comment: Will do! We just woke up here in Belgium :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you are missing in your post, is that the leapfrog method is not unstable when $\lambda$ is purely imaginary, which can be the case in many real-world applications, such as hyperbolic problems in fluid dynamics or electromagnetism.

The next thing is that the region you've given is not for ***stability*** but for ***A-stability***. The leapfrog method actually can be stable in the case where $h$ is constant, so even when $\textrm{Re}(\lambda) \ne 0$ it still can converge, it just doesn't satisfy the criteria for absolute stability ([it also says this on pg 53 of this PDF](https://math.unm.edu/%7Enitsche/courses/471/classnotes.pdf), and the difference between "stability" and "A-stability" can be seen on pg 36 of the same PDF).

Computations with a 0-stable method can also be unstable (see [7.1 of this PDF, for example](https://archive.siam.org/books/ot98/sample/OT98Chapter7.pdf), but that's another matter.

Comment: It was past 3am when I wrote that, so I kept it brief (and hopefully it's still coherent!), but I got the ping from you less than an hour ago and your bounty suggests you wanted an answer quickly.